# Odoo 8 deploy website with reverse proxy (apache2)

Tags: apache2, odoo, reverse-proxy, odoo-8, domain-name

Hello I'd like to deploy my website using Apache2, my domainname is www.hew-automation.be. I've already made a link from this domainname to my server's IP Address (http://91.183.84.209:8080/). I want to get rid of the port 8080 and also stop displaying the IP address in the browser.

I installed apache2, added following to /etc/apache2/sites-available/odoo.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hew-automation.be
    ServerAlias *.hew-automation.be // Use this if you want dbfillter on subdomain
    ErrorLog /var/log/odoo/odoo-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/odoo/odoo-access.log combined
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyVia On
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

Then enabled this with a2ensite, this without any errors.

This is my /etc/odoo-server.conf file:

```
[options]
admin_passwd = XXXX
db_host = False 
db_port = False
db_user = XXXX
db_password = XXXX
addons_path = /opt/odoo/addons
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
xmlrpc_port = 8068
```

Now whenever I surf to my IP-address http://91.183.84.209/, it always shows the default page of Apache2, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.